# Number of connected components in a graph from G(n,m)

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, pr.probability

Hello,

$G(n,m)$ is the family of all graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges (I consider $m < n$).
Each graph in $G(n,m)$ is selected with uniform probability.
What is the probability that the graph selected has exactly $c$ connected components?

An equivalent question is: what is the probability that exactly $k$ edges should be removed from the selected graph in order to make it a forest (graph without cycles)?

There is a solution for the case of $k = 0$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57062/probability-that-a-graph-g-does-not-contain-a-cycle).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what $m$ and $k$ are. If $m$ is of order $Cn$ then the number of components is roughly Gaussian with mean and variance of order $n$. This should give the correct probability for $k$ reasonably close to the median. It should be possible to compute the rate function if $k$ is much larger or smaller.

If $m$ is larger, the Gaussian behaviour persists with different normalization until $m\approx n\log n$. At that scale, the number of components becomes Poisson. This persists up to much higher $n$, though once $m>n\log n$ the graph is connected with high probability.

If you are interested in a particular regime of $m,k$, I or others could probably give more details or references.